# missing 1 required positional argument - python

Tags: mysql, python

Estoy practicando con clases, objetos y bases de datos. No puedo hacer que este código funcione y no estoy seguro de qué estoy haciendo mal.
Recibo

```
TypeError: nuevo_articulo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'precio'
```

Aquí está mi código:

```
import mysql.connector

class Manejo_stock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conexion = mysql.connector.connect(host ="localhost",user="root", passwd="", database="articulos")
        self.cursor1= self.conexion.cursor() # abro un cursor para recorrer y enventualmente modificar los datos

    def nuevo_articulo(self,articulo, cantidad, precio):
        nuevo_articulo = articulo, precio, cantidad
        sql = 'insert into articulos (articulo, cantidad, precio) values (%s, %s, %s)'
        self.cursor1.execute(sql, nuevo_articulo)
        self.conexion.commit()
        self.conexion.close()
        return nuevo_articulo
        print("Se agregado correctamente el articulo")

articulo1 = Manejo_stock()
articulo1 = Manejo_stock.nuevo_articulo('peras', 5, 23.5)
```

Comment: Tu Id de la tabla es autoincrementable?

Comment: si, si. la tabla tiene 4 filas, codigo (primary y autoincrementable), articulo, cantidad y precio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes algunos errores de concepto.

- Dentro del método `nuevo_articulo()`, al final, tienes un `print()` después del `return`. Obviamente debería estar antes, pues una vez que haces `return` ya no se ejecutará el resto de la función.
- Para invocar el método `nuevo_articulo()`, debes hacerlo *sobre un objeto*, y no sobre la clase. Eso es lo que te está fallando ya que cuando haces `objeto.metodo(parametros)`, Python lo traduce a `Clase.metodo(objeto, parametros)`, haciendo que el objeto en cuestión pase a ser `self` dentro del método. Al llamarlo como `Clase.metodo(parametros)`, que es lo que has hecho, faltaría un parámetro en la llamada (python no puede saber cuál y supone que es el último, `precio`, pero en realidad era el primero, `self`).
- Cuando "invocas" una clase, así `Clase()`, se ejecuta su constructor y se retorna un objeto de esa clase. En tu caso, ya que la clase se llama `Manejo_stock`, el objeto creado podría llamarse `manejador`, en lugar de `articulo1`, pues no es un artículo. Esto hace más comprensible el código.

Así pues, quedaría en la forma siguiente:

```
import mysql.connector

class Manejo_stock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conexion = mysql.connector.connect(host ="localhost",user="root", passwd="", database="articulos")
        self.cursor1= self.conexion.cursor() # abro un cursor para recorrer y enventualmente modificar los datos

    def nuevo_articulo(self,articulo, cantidad, precio):
        nuevo_articulo = articulo, precio, cantidad
        sql = 'insert into articulos (articulo, cantidad, precio) values (%s, %s, %s)'
        self.cursor1.execute(sql, nuevo_articulo)
        self.conexion.commit()
        self.conexion.close()
        print("Se agregado correctamente el articulo")
        return nuevo_articulo


manejador = Manejo_stock()
articulo1 = manejador.nuevo_articulo('peras', 5, 23.5)
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! ahora me quedó mucho más claro